# How to generate and/or improve this power distribution for these 4 subsystems?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I am trying to design a system that is powered through a 28V wall adapter and a 6S cells LiPo battery. The system has a subsystem that takes care of the balanced charge, coulomb counter, charge control and protection, automatic power selection from adapter or battery, etc.

The output voltage of this subsystem is up to 28V (when the system is powered by the adapter) and at least up to 18V when it is powered by the battery (and it is about to run out). The maximum current that can provide this subsystem is at least 8.5A. The system works through the wall adapter and when it is removed, it automatically powers through the battery (the behavior is similar to that of a laptop).

Starting from the output of this subsystem: Vout_min = 18V, Vout_max = 28V, Iout_max = 8.5A, I have to design the power of the following subsystems:

- Subsystem 1: Vin=24V and consumption less than 1.75A
- Subsystem 2: Vin=24V and consumption less than 0.75A
- Subsystem 3: Vin=19V and consumption less than 2A
- Subsystem 4: Vin=5V and consumption less than 1.5A

In addition, it is necessary to power two  24V fans but as they have a wide range of operation, they will operate with MOSFETs working as switches.

I had thought to use this configuration:

*For the subsystems 1 and 2*: a DC-DC switch converter with a buck-boost topology. Vout=24V and up to Iout=3A. And then, with a pair of MOSFETs as switches, to control the power of subsystems 1 and 2.

*For the subsystem 3*: a DC-DC switch converter with a buck-boost topology. Vout=19V and up to Iout=2.5A.

*For the subsystem 4*: I had thought to use a DC-DC switch converter with a buck topology. Vout=5V and up to Iout=2A.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT5Kzo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It would be interesting to maintain an efficiency above 90% and try to minimize the number and cost of components.

**My questions are related to the power distribution**:

1. Is it minimally acceptable?
2. If not, how would you do it?
3. How can it be improved?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing comes immediately to mind. Your GPIO will most likley not tolerate being pulled up to 24 V. If it’s just a simplified schematic representation and you will solve it down the line, then no problem. If you on the other hand connect it directly to an MCU, Aurdoino or similar, you will fry it.

Comment: @winny Indeed it is only a simplified schematic but thank you very much for your comment. I simply wanted to show that the subsystem 1 and 2 is powered through two mosfets respectively